# Wrapping ng-bootstrap datepicker in custom component

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

We are using the `ng-bootstrap` component library with Angular 2.

We'd like to keep the `ngb-datepicker` wrapped under a different selector in a new component. So that it can be swapped with another date picker if needed.

Basically, we'd like to use, 
`<custom-datepicker>` instead of `<ngb-datepicker>`
The component will have the same set of inputs.

One way of getting this done would be to keep the  in a custom component. and pass the inputs from the component.

```
@Component({
selector: 'custom-datepicker',
template: '<uib-datepicker ...pass the inputs here ></uib-datepicker>',
})
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: You will need to implement ControlValueAccessor to use [(ngModel)] with your custom-datepicker

Comment: @VincentV. That's true. I'm reading up on it and will pass the value back using that. 
Apart from that, the rest of the values can be passed down with inputs is it? What about handling any events that may be fired? Just capture them and call an Output event?

Comment: @nipuna777 did you succeed? And if so can you share the code and tell us if it works with NgModel and with FormControls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to implement ControlValueAccessor to use `[(ngModel)]` with your custom-datepicker. You can find plenty of tutorials, try to find one that is not too old (> august 2016 ) as it has changed quite a bit since beta.

Then, you need to define how your custom component needs to react, and then bind everything you need to the inner control (in your case, the uib-datepicker).

That means :

- Input() for what you want to be parametered when calling your custom component
- Output() event emitters that you emit when you catch an event from your inner control